# How to implement zooming *and* paging like iOS Photos app

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

In Apple's photo's app you can swipe between photos while viewing, and also zoom into and pan around a photo.  When you get to the edge of a zoomed photo you can still swipe into the next image - what kind of scrollview setup is needed to allow this?

Answer (score 5):

There's an excellent video from WWDC 2010 - https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/

The session is titled "Designing Apps with Scroll Views". It's a step-by-step of exactly what you're asking.

Per omz's response, the paging scroller part is pretty straight forward. But Apple does some more complex things with how the zoomable scroll views are created and reused. You really should check out the video.

Comment: Yep; very good session -- they don't just show how to set something like this up, but how to make it perform well, too.

Comment: I do not understand why there must be 2 images loaded. My guess is that we need 3 - one visible and 1 on each side which are preloaded, so when the user is scrolling they do not see anything being loaded.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this is to create one scroll view that scrolls only horizontally and has `pagingEnabled` set to `YES`. Each page of this scroll view then contains another zoomable scroll view for an individual photo.

Comment: I think he asked how to embed a scrollview within a scrollview and then advance to the next page on the outer scrollview at some point. Just like the photos app works.