# How do we detect swipe gesture when we zoom uiscrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I have `UIImageview` as a subview of `UIScrollview`, I can zoom in or out by using this 
tutorial http://cocoadevblog.heroku.com/iphone-tutorial-uiimage-with-zooming-tapping-rotation, the problem is how can I detect swipe gesture when I zoom `UIScrollview` in,
I know how to implement swipe gesture, and it work normally except when I zoom `UIScrollview` in.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: If both were gesture recognizer you could have used [aRecognizerSwipe requireGestureRecognizerToFail:aRecognizerZoom]. If it is not, you might have to try implementing the scrollview delegate to findout if user has swiped -(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;

Comment: I had a similar problem where I had a few views in a scrollview, but I wanted to be able to drag the image in each view.  The solution: I made the scrollview only work when using 2 fingers.  Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @ACB Thank you very much for your reply, unfortunately in my case, it's not work.

Comment: @WolfLink ,thank you very much for your reply, but it's not quite what I am looking for. If we made the scrollview only work when using 2 fingers, I afraid that some user may be don't understand, if I am wrong please correct me, thanks.

Comment: @piam yes, I did have that problem sometimes.  Some users tried two fingers instinctively, others needed to be told.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at following links,hope it helps ..

[How to implement zooming *and* paging like iOS Photos app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476302/how-to-implement-zooming-and-paging-like-ios-photos-app)

[How to implement Swipe Gesture for UIImageView randomizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689519/how-to-implement-swipe-gesture-for-uiimageview-randomizer)

Comment: thank you very much for link, but it's not quite what I am looking for.